# Using string key to access Firestore map value gives IDE warning that string was never read

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that reads a document from Firestore, gets a map field, and gets a `boolean` value from one of that map's keys. However, my IDE says that the `string` key I use to get the value from the map (`someKey` in the code below) is "declared but never read", which puzzles me. Aren't I reading it when I use it to access the map? What am I doing wrong?

```
exports.someFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, _context) => {
    const uid = data.uid;
    const someKey = data.someKey; // function argument; guaranteed to be a string

    const settingsDoc = await admin.firestore().doc("settings/" + uid).get();
    const theMapInQuestion = settingsDoc.get("theMapInQuestion"); // guaranteed to be a Firestore map of type [string: boolean]
    const theBooleanInQuestion = theMapInQuestion.someKey;

    if (theBooleanInQuestion === true) {
        // proceed
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that you never used the const `someKey` after it was declared.  Indeed, I do not see where that variable is ever used in the code you show here.  You could certainly delete the line of code that declares `someKey` and it would work exactly the same.

The only thing you're doing wrong that I can see is assuming that the const is actually being used when the compiler says it's not. (It's rarely a good idea to doubt the compiler.)

If you intended to access the property with the value of the `someKey` variable, then you meant to write `theMapInQuestion[someKey]`.

Comment: `const theBooleanInQuestion = theMapInQuestion.someKey;` is where I use the key. Or is this the wrong way to access the values of this map?

Comment: That line of code is accessing the `someKey` property of `theMapInQuestion`.  It is literally using that name `someKey`.  It is not using the const you declared earlier.  If you intended to access the property with the value of the `someKey` variable, then you meant to write `theMapInQuestion[someKey]`.